# Moved SSL cert - now getting java.security.cer.CertPathValidatorException

Tags: java, android, ssl

I recently moved my backend (rails) to Digital Ocean. I installed my ssl cert (signed by a CA) there and browsers recognize and display accordingly in the web app.

I went to do some work on and my Android client - only to get this exception from Volley:

```
10-06 16:57:20.448: D/Error.Response(10668): com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

I'm not sure how to handle this. When I had the cert installed at Heroku initially I didn't see this - only after moving the cert. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error came about because the certificate I had installed on my server was a primary cert with no chain. I concatenated the secondary cert with the primary into a single file, installed on the server, and Android accepted the SSL connection.

A lot of resources I saw talked about writing a custom trust manager etc. I would try to test your cert chain first and correct it before doing a bunch of that other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not work in the app but works in the browser it is often the problem, that the site uses server name indication (SNI) to have multiple certificates on a single IP address. This is supported by all modern browsers, but not by the old Apache HTTP client shipped with Android.

For more details see [HttpClient generates SSLException after acquiring new domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886771/apache-httpclient-generates-sslexception-after-acquiring-new-domain-name) or [Android SSL - SNI support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879894/android-ssl-sni-support).

Comment: This didn't end up being my issue. Mine was actually unrelated to Android but the answer resides in that error. The certificate chain wasn't complete. I had to concatenate the intermediate certs with the primary cert into a single file and that fixed the issue.